# How progress bar works with percentages in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone

How progress bar works with percentaages in objective-c.like depending on votes it displays the percentage

Comment: Look at here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progressbar

Comment: This is a very basic question regarding progress bar. You could have easily found its answer on web/google.

Answer (score 2):

It takes value from 0 to 1

0 means 0% and 1 means 100%

you can do like

```
progressBar.setProgress(floatPercentage/100.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find percentage with the following formula

```
int totalVote,givenVote;
float percentage = givenVote * 100 / totalVote;
```

now set this percentage in progress bar

```
UIProgressView *progressView;
progressView.progress = (percentage / 100.0);
```